# Docker-compose django-python container communication

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

So I am running a django node and a regular python script using docker-compose. The python script regularly asks django backend for data. However, when I `docker-compose up` I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d6e45dc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py wait_for_db && 
             python3 manage.py migrate &&
             python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  monitor:
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 main.py"
    build:
      context: ./monitor
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./monitor:/monitor
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
```

from `monitor` I do:

```
response = requests.get(url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/')
```

What is a correct way to communicate between nodes in docker?

P.S Cors origins are allowed in django

Comment: Use the name of the service as the hostname - `url='http://backend:8080/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't connect because from within the monitor container, backend is not at `0.0.0.0` but at a address assigned by docker within the default network it creates.
And the service name is the alias for the container ip.
So backend service can be accessed via the alias `backend`

Read more about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

To make it work. Change the monitor script to

`requests.get(url = 'http://backend:8080')`

Comment: I've tried it out, but still gives the same error, just with "backend":
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='backend', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffb168bec10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: How about if you use `http://backend` does that work?

Comment: Looks somehow for me like a django issue, but django itself is working in browser

Comment: Without the port it uses port 80:
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='backend', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa55b122160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: Yes.. try with port `http://backend:8080`

Comment: Yeap, tried it already, the resulting error is in first comment to this answer (((

Comment: Okay, changes smth and it worked. Thanks a lot! Do I use the same in production?

Comment: Yes. It'll work